# How to make TightVNC, TigerVNC, TurboVNC and other VNC servers run on a non-standard port

Tags: server, vnc

I used to run the default VNC server (/usr/lib/vino/vino-server) but it is unable show VirtualBox VMs. So, I have installed TurboVNC, which is designed to support 3D and shows my VirtualBox VMs all right.

However, TurboVNC and all these other TightVNC derivatives run on 5901 or 5902. I would like to make them run on 5900 but there doesn't seem to be an option to do so.

How can I run Turbo, Tiger, Tight VNC servers on port 5900. If I could do this, then I could make TurboVNC the default VNC server on several computers and VMs.

(I know that VirtualBox has an RDP option but I want to see the host desktop along with the VMs too. So, TurboVNC on the host is my choice.)

Answer (score 5):

For TightVNC the default port is 5900 plus the display number, so 5901 for the first display, etc.

The server has an undocumented command-line option to override this port number

```
-rfbport 5900
```

Should manually set the port number to 5900.  Experiment with it.

Comment: +1... the option is not really undocumented though: it's an option that's passed transparently to the underlying Xvnc process, and is documented under `man Xvnc`